# Image depending on screen left size

Tags: css, image

So I have a sidebar is left side ( 100px ) and then I have a image on the right side. Is it posible to resize the image depending on size which has left no the right side?

For example :

```
<div id="sidebar"></div> 
<img src="image" alt="Work">

<style>
#sidebar {
float: left;
width: 100px;
background: red; 
height: 500px;
}
img {
float: left;
width: 80%; /* This is not working right */
}
</style>
```

**EDIT** : So example would be - If my resolution is 1000px then image size width would be 900px. And sidebar would always be on right side and it would be 100px wide.

There is fiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/qLnZu/4/

Comment: Your "left" has a fixed width, so when should your image resize? Do you mean you want the image to be as big as what remains on the right side of the sidebar?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I see that you have a 100px wide sidebar on the left and an image on the right. I don't understand "Is it posible to resize the image depending on size which has left no the right side?" Could you explain it more or show me what you want it to look like?

Comment: @CoryDanielson I have added the example to my post.

Comment: @NathanQ I have added the example to my post

Comment: @iKaspars Ok, see answer below, hope this is what you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap a div around the img tag:

```
<div id="sidebar">
</div> 
<div id="right">
   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/sports/" alt="Work">
</div>
```

And in CSS:

```
#sidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  background: red; 
  height: 500px;
}

#right {
  margin-left: 100px; //width of sidebar
}

#right img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

**example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/qLnZu/6/

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure how to do it without javascript.

But I threw this simple fiddle together for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/4VrvN/

```
$('img').width($(window).width() - 100 + 'px');
```

Comment: Hmm.. It works. Only thing if I resize the browser windows I have to refresh the page. But it isnt a huge problem. I hope so....